# Проблемы с голосовым ассистентом

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

Всем привет! Я имею проблему с голосовым ассистентом при запросе не реагирует на запросы. Но это не ошибка потому что она не отображается

```
import json
import pvporcupine
import pyaudio
import time
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from vosk import Model, KaldiRecognizer
import vosk
import config
from pvrecorder import PvRecorder

with open('Json/commands.json', 'r') as file:
    commands_data = json.load(file)
    commands = commands_data.get('commands', [])

porcupine = pvporcupine.create(access_key='1Z9KvyECJVK9skD58L9D0ayAhZI91t4fWDl7OFmI8VB9QXc1BRAIlQ==', keyword_paths=['Neyro/hey_gosha.ppn'])

model = vosk.Model("vosk")
samplerate = 16000
device = config.MICROPHONE_INDEX
kaldi_rec = vosk.KaldiRecognizer(model, samplerate)

def find_best_command(user_speech):
    max_ratio = 0
    best_command = None

    for command in commands:
        activation_phrase = command['activation_phrase']
        ratio = fuzz.ratio(user_speech, activation_phrase)
        if ratio > max_ratio:
            max_ratio = ratio
            best_command = command
        if best_command and max_ratio > 10:
            return best_command
    
def execute_command(command):
    if command['action'] == 'time':
        current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M", time.localtime())
        response_text = f"{command['response']} {current_time}"
    elif command['action'] == 'wait':
        response_text = command['response']
    elif command['action'] == 'song':
        response_text = command['response']
        # тип песня

    return response_text
        
def listen_and_recognize_continuous():
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=samplerate, input=True, frames_per_buffer=porcupine.frame_length)
    print("Слушаю...")

    start_time = time.time()

    while True:
        data = stream.read(porcupine.frame_length)
        if kaldi_rec.AcceptWaveform(data):
            result = json.loads(kaldi_rec.Result())
            user_speech = result.get('text', '')
            if user_speech:
                print(f"user said: {user_speech}")

                command = find_best_command(user_speech)
                if command:
                    response = execute_command(command)
                    print(response)

                start_time = time.time()

        if time.time() - start_time > 7:
            print("Время ожидания истекло.")
            break

    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    p.terminate()

recorder = PvRecorder(device_index=config.MICROPHONE_INDEX, frame_length=porcupine.frame_length)
recorder.start()
print('Используемое устройство: %s' % recorder.selected_device)

print(f"Гоша начал свою работу ...")

while True:
    try:
        pcm = recorder.read()
        keyword_index = porcupine.process(pcm)

        if keyword_index >= 0:
            listen_and_recognize_continuous()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Остановка...")
        recorder.stop()
        break
```

Вот Json файл если интересно:

```
{
  "commands": [
    {
      "activation_phrase": "сколько времени",
      "action": "time",
      "response": "Текущее время:"
    },
    {
      "activation_phrase": "подожди минутку",
      "action": "wait",
      "response": "Жду"
    },
    {
      "activation_phrase": "спой мне песню",
      "action": "song",
      "response": "Пою!"
    }
  ]
}
```